# Styling a xul scrollbar

Tags: xul, xulrunner

XUL makes when loading a scrollbar in the richlistbox. I want to style this scrollbar, I've tried everything but nothing helps.

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to make CSS style changes to portions of an XUL element you need to assign the CSS to the underlying elements when they are contained within the primary element. In order to determine what elements are within which (i.e. what elements make up a <scrollbar>). You will probably end up using a combination of the *DOM Inspector*, examining the .xml file which define them, and the CSS used to style them. The files which define the XUL elements are .xml binding files. These, and the .css files for their styles, are normally contained within the *omni.ja* files that are within the Firefox install directory tree. omni.ja files are just regular .zip files which have been renamed with a different extension.  You can copy such a file and rename it to *omni.zip* to get convenient access.

Specifically for scrollbars, these appear to be *scrollbar.xml* and *scrollbars.css* which are located in the main *omni.ja*.  You may also want to look at the *floating-scrollbars-light.css* or *floating-scrollbars.css* files in the *browser/omni.ja* file.

However, you want the scrollbar inside `<richlistbox>`.  To find out how to style those scrollbars, you need to find what makes up a `<richlistbox>;`. That file is `richlistbox.xml` (styled in *richlistbox.css*) in the main *omni.ja*. In that file it appears the scrollbar is implemented by a `<scrollbox>` element which is defined in *scrollbox.xml* (styled in *scrollbox.css*), also in the main *omni.ja*. The element(s) you want to style may be contained within several layers of other elements. You will need to keep digging and experimenting to find the right CSS selector for the element(s) you want to style.

You may already be using the `<richlistbox>` in your own XUL window, but you might also be just adding one somewhere to the browser (You did not say). For experimenting, in addition to the development setup, I would suggest a separate XUL window, which specifies a separate .css file, which you can open easily by clicking a button. This could just be the options dialog. Using a separate XUL window for experimenting allows you to have a separate CSS file called by just that window. When such is the case, the .xul file for that window (and the .js and .css files called only from that .xul) are re-read each time it the window is opened. Doing this makes testing changes possible with just closing and re-opening the window rather than having to re-start Firefox. If it is a completely separate widow, rather than the options dialog, you can open multiple copies of the window and do side-by-side comparisons between changes.

As an example, the following CSS colors the background of the actual text area within <menulist> and <textbox> elements when the mouse hovers over them:

```
menulist hbox :hover {
  background-color: Azure !important;
}
textbox>hbox :hover {
  background-color: Azure !important;
}
```

Comment: I added more text specifically about the makeup of <richlistbox> and experimenting.